# MySQL DELETE With Limit After Offset

Tags: mysql, syntax, limit, sql-delete, offset

Hopefully this is a simple question and I'm overlooking something trivial, but I can't seem to find the answer in quite a bit of searching.

When doing a SELECT query, I can do LIMIT like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 20,20
```

That retrieves up to 20 rows starting with an offset of 20.

Now, suppose that I want to delete those rows I selected?

One might expect to be able to do this:

```
DELETE FROM `table` LIMIT 20,20
```

However, for whatever reason, this isn't part of MySQL syntax.

One solution which works if the table had an `id` field would be:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` >= 20 LIMIT 20
```

However, it requires me to find what the 20th `id` value is first, and requires that there be an `id` field. Not all of my tables have `id` fields. It also will give different results if table rows are in a different order than ascending by `id`.

I'm trying to find a generic solution because I'm dealing with tables that have a wide variety of different columns, so I can't depend on any particular column to exist. A few of my tables don't even have a primary index.

For my particular application, I'm removing some cells from the end of the table that got copied erroneously, but I'm curious if there's a clever solution to remove from the middle as well.

Anyway, I appreciate any help or ideas! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `LIMIT` subquery as follows:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM (SELECT id FROM yourTable ORDER BY id LIMIT 20) t
);
```

Comment: Single LIMIT (w/o OFFSET) is supported in DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM `table` t1
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT * 
               FROM `table` 
               ORDER BY {expression} LIMIT 20,20 ) t2
```

LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense - hence ORDER BY with expression placeholder is added.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e1dddb581810ca6fae6983634527cb7)

PS. Of course you may use not NATURAL joining but INNER one with proper joining expression (for example, by primary key, or by sorting expression if it provides rows uniqueness).